# How to Skip a Database in mysqlcheck for Analyzing, Rebuilding, and Optimizing InnoDB Tables

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysqlcheck

There's a command to optimize and repair all databases:

```
mysqlcheck --user=root --password=PASSWORD_FOR_ROOT --auto-repair --optimize --all-databases
```

How can I skip a single, specific database from this process, while optimizing and repairing the other databases? `--skip-database=DATABASE_NAME` seems like it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey, Stas!  Any chance you've had a chance to review the answers posted and accept one of them?  I believe the thing you said "seems like it doesn't work" actually does work, based on my own tests and what others have posted.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mysql 8.0, you can skip one database with --skip-database=<db_name>; for instance:

```
mysqlcheck --user=root --password=PASSWORD_FOR_ROOT --optimize --all-databases --skip-database=<db_name>
```

However, <db_name> is ignored if it is mysql, at least on Ubuntu with mysql-server 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.10.2.
But this issue has been fixed with mysql 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.22.10.1.

Comment: You are a brilliant, amazing person!  Thank you so much.  I needed this to solve skipping the `mysql` DB, which I think is just where DigitalOcean puts schema stuff.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't skip data base but you can specify specific database for optimization.

```
mysqlcheck --user=root --password=PASSWORD_FOR_ROOT --auto-repair --optimize ----all-in-1 dbname
```

Where dbname is the name of database.